# Removing the text from drupal custom menu

Tags: php, drupal-6

I'm trying to style a custom menu within drupal.

I've sucessfully styled  to display a background image, but the problem is that the menu item title still displays. So I get a nice image, with  blazoned all over it.

Is there a template function I could use to format the custom menu and remove the text portion from the hyperlink?

I've done something similar on my primary links (see below) but I could do with some help figuring out how to do so on the custom menus.

```
function primary_links_add_icons() {
  $links = menu_primary_links();
  $level_tmp = explode('-', key($links));
  $level = $level_tmp[0];
  $output = "<ul class=\"links-$level\">\n";   
  if ($links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $link = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['attributes'], $link['query'], $link['fragment']);
        $cssid = str_replace(' ', '_', strip_tags($link));
        $link = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $link);
        $output .= '<li id="'.$cssid.'">' . $link .'</li>';
    };
    $output .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

And then this called within the page.tpl.php

```
print primary_links_add_icons();
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theme_menu_tree` would be the way to resolve this on the `template.php` itself. The meat of your function would be identical to your function above. Documentation is at http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_tree

But, I would recommend using CSS for what you're doing. If the text is removed entirely (via php) then you'll be depending on the user's browser to display the images and CSS properly and make navigation possible.

You might consider including both the image and the text, but making the text portion `display: none` so that it degrades more gracefully if CSS isn't loaded properly.

Comment: The problem is that the source is:

<li class="leaf first">
<a title="" href="/testing/benecol/index.php?q=recipes"><none></a>
</li>

So there is no way I can think of to display the <A> tag but NOT display the text within it.

Comment: A common trick to 'remove' the text when using background images is to move the text outside the viewport via a **text-indent:-9999px;** style in CSS.

Comment: 8 years developing HTML and I never knew that.. great, thank you!

Comment: I'm curious why you're using background images instead or normal <img> tags. If you used <img>, you could solve the whole problem in one swoop by adding the title to the alt tags.

Comment: @anschauung: If you write or generate the links yourself, `<img>` tags are an option, but if you're styling other peoples output or, like in this case, CMS generated stuff, this might not be possible at all or at least a lot of work. Additionally, text links are more accessible (Think search engine crawler, screen reader, etc.)

Comment: @Henrik: hfidgen is completely rewriting the link output with PHP -- note the regex in the posted code. I agree that text links are more accessible, fwiw, but I was more curious why the poster was using background images instead of <img> tags.